# How to change the text of a textView after a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-button

I tried to setup a pendingIntent which evokes the method "shrinkTheNumber()" of the class "shrinkNumber.java" after the button is clicked.

**The Problem is that at the point of envoking that method i get the following error:**

*Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(android.content.Context, void)*

*com.example.myapplication.shrinkNumber*

*public static void shrinkTheNumber(@NonNull Context context)*

I can't figure out what the problem is.

The goal of the whole program is that the text of the textView gets changed when the button is clicked.

**class shrinkNumber:**

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.widget.RemoteViews;
public class shrinkNumber {

    public static void shrinkTheNumber(Context context)

    {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "hello");
        updatewidgetnow(context, remoteViews);
    }

    public static void updatewidgetnow (Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews){
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widgetComponent, remoteViews);


    }
}
```

**Here is the part with the pendingIntent:**

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent shrinkIntent = new Intent(context, shrinkNumber.shrinkTheNumber(context));

        PendingIntent shrinkPendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,shrinkIntent,0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, shrinkPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is this line (`new Intent(context, shrinkNumber.shrinkTheNumber(context));`) - what are you trying to pass as the second argument there to the Intent constructor? `shrinkTheNumber` returns void - and as the error message says you can't construct an Intent with a `Context` and a `void`...

Answer (score 0):

Intent is Android's native way to change from one activity to another. These do not change anything in the target/starting point class. There is no direct way to pass the context to the target activity using Intent. Similarly you can't call a particular method from intent. But there is a workaround for this, you can do something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, shrinkNumber.class);
intent.putExtra("methodName","shrinkTheNumber");
```

and then in the called activity , you can take the intent and decide which method to call like this:

```
if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("shrinkTheNumber")){
      shrinkTheNumber();
   }
```

Hope it helps